# Python using Regular Expression to convert a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to convert the duration variable from YouTube Data api?

PT1M6S --> 1:06
PT38S --> 0:38
PT58M4 --> 58:04

Here is my codes:
p['duration'] is the value from json data

```
duration = re.sub(r'^PT',r'',p['duration'])
duration = re.sub(r'M',r':',duration)
if (len(p['duration']) > 5 ):
    duration = re.sub(r'S',r'',duration)
else:
    duration = "0:" + re.sub(r'S',r'',duration)
```

Is there a simple way to do in one regex statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to using a regex is using `parser` from `dateutil`. It has an option `fuzzy` that you can use to convert your data to `datetime`. If you subtract midnight today from that, you get the value as a `timedelta`:

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

lst = ['PT1M6S','PT38S', 'PT58M4']

for t in lst:
    print(parser.parse(t, fuzzy=True) - datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.min.time()))
```

gives you

```
0:01:06
0:00:38
0:58:04
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
import re
strings = ['PT1M6S', 'PT38S', 'PT58M4']
rx = re.compile(r'^PT(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)S?)?$')
for s in strings:
  print(s, ' => ', rx.sub(lambda x: f"{(x.group(1) or '00').zfill(2)}:{(x.group(2) or '00').zfill(2)}", s))
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/2wYwHs). Output:

```py
PT1M6S  =>  01:06
PT38S  =>  00:38
PT58M4  =>  58:04
```

The regex demo is `^PT(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)S?)?$`, it matches

- `^PT` - `PT` at the start of a string
- `(?:(\d+)M)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1+ digits (capturing them into Group 1) and an `M` char
- `(?:(\d+)S?)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1+ digits (capturing them into Group 2) and an optional `S` char
- `$` - end of string.